# Product of two multivariate normal probability density functions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I think this is a duplicate of [Product of two multivariate normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495719/product-of-two-multivariate-normal-distribution), but I think the answer that is accepted there does not answer the question.

So given

$$Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$$
$$X = AY + N$$
where $N \sim \mathcal{N}(0, S) $

How do we determine $$ Y | X $$

One way would be $$p(Y=y|X=x) = p(X=x|Y=y)\cdot p(Y=y)/p(X=x)$$
The $1/p(X=x)$ term is just a normalisation, so we can check that $p(X=x|Y=y)\cdot p(Y=y)$ is the pdf of a multivariate normal by writing out the exponentials.

But I am looking specifically for a proof that does not go into the exponentials and instead relies on known facts about normal distributions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $Y$ is an $n\times1$ column vector, $N$ is an $m\times 1$ column vector, and $Y$ and $N$ are independent. For $X$ to make sense, $A$ must then be an $m\times n$ matrix. Stack $Y$ on top of $X$ into an $(m+n)\times 1$ column vector $W$. Writing
$$
W:=\begin{pmatrix}Y\\ X\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}I &0 \\ A &I\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}Y\\N\end{pmatrix},
$$
we see that $W$ has multivariate normal distribution. Calculate the covariance matrix of $W$ using the formula $\operatorname{Var}(BU)=B\operatorname{Var}(U)B^T$:
$$\operatorname{Var}(W)=\operatorname{Var}\begin{pmatrix}Y\\ X\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\Sigma_{Y,Y}&\Sigma_{Y,X}\\ \Sigma_{X,Y}&\Sigma_{X,X}\end{pmatrix}:=
\begin{pmatrix}\Sigma & \Sigma A^T\\A\Sigma & A\Sigma A^T + S\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Use [this result](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/270934/145128) to find that the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ is multivariate normal with conditional mean
$$E(Y\mid X=x)=E(Y) + \Sigma_{Y,X} \Sigma_{X,X}^{-1}[x-E(X)]=\mu +\Sigma A^T(A\Sigma A^T+S)^{-1}x$$
and conditional variance
$$\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X=x)=\Sigma_{Y,Y} - \Sigma_{Y,X}\Sigma_{X,X}^{-1}\Sigma_{X,Y}=\Sigma - \Sigma A^T(A\Sigma A^T+S)^{-1}A\Sigma .
$$